# R: count number of matches in matrix row

Tags: r, matrix, character, row

I have a matrix `mat`.

```
mat<-matrix(
c('a','a','b','a','b','b'),  
nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

**I want to make a vector of the count matches in each row of the matrix**. For example, let's say I wanted to count the number of matches of the letter `a` in each row. The first row of the matrix has an `a`,`a`: two matches of `a`. The second row of the matrix has an `a`,`b`: one match of `a`.

I can count the number of matches of the character `a` in a row with this line of code:

```
sum(!is.na(charmatch(mat[1,c(1,2)],"a"))) # first row, returns 2
sum(!is.na(charmatch(mat[2,c(1,2)],"a"))) # second row, returns 1
```

I want to vectorize this counting procedure. In other words, I want to do something like this

```
as.vector(rowsum(!is.na(charmatch(mat[,c(1,2)], "a"))))
```

So that it returns a vector like this `2,1,0` which means 2 matches of `a` in row 1 of the matrix, 1 match of `a` in row 2 of the matrix, 0 matches of `a` in row 3 of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
rowSums(mat=='a', na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 2 1 0
```

For all `unique` values

```
 Un <- sort(unique(c(mat)))
 res <- sapply(Map(`==`, list(mat), Un), rowSums, na.rm=TRUE)
 colnames(res) <- Un
 res
 #     a b
 #[1,] 2 0
 #[2,] 1 1
 #[3,] 0 2
```

Or as contributed by @Ananda Mahto, a faster approach would be

```
 lvl <- sort(unique(c(mat)))
 vapply(lvl, function(x) rowSums(mat == x, na.rm = TRUE), numeric(nrow(mat)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this for all values, you can try one of the following:

`table` with `factor` in `apply`

```
levs <- unique(c(mat))
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) table(factor(x, levs))))
#      a b
# [1,] 2 0
# [2,] 1 1
# [3,] 0 2
```

`melt` and `dcast` with `fun.aggregate = length` from "reshape2"

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(mat), Var1 ~ value, value.var = "Var2")
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#   Var1 a b
# 1    1 2 0
# 2    2 1 1
# 3    3 0 2
```

---

Better yet would just be `table` after manually creating the values to tabulate:

```
table(rep(sequence(nrow(mat)), ncol(mat)), c(mat))
#    
#     a b
#   1 2 0
#   2 1 1
#   3 0 2
```